# Linking to sub tab page doesn’t allow tab to go to main page

Tags: ionic-framework

Here is a sample of my structure.

```
Home
Closure
| - Inside Page 1
Progress
Resources
| - Inside Page 2
```

My first problem is when clicking a link to "Inside Page 2" from "Home" the back button doesn't show. That's fine (for me at least, not sure about project owners). My main problem is when I click on the 'Resources' tab, it will not take me to that view. It only shows "Inside Page 2". I can only get to "Resources" if I had visited that tab first.

Here are my states for that inside page and the main tab page.

```
.state('tab.resources', {
    url: '/resources',
    views: {
        'tab-resources': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-resources.html',
            controller: 'NothingCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('tab.resources.social', {
    url: '/social',
    views: {
        'tab-resources@tab': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/resources/social.html',
            controller: 'SocialCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Here is my tabs.html.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

    <!-- Home Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="mb-icon icon-home" ui-sref="tab.home">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Closures Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Closures" icon="mb-icon icon-closures" ui-sref="tab.closures">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-closures"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Progress Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Progress" icon="mb-icon icon-progress" ui-sref="tab.progress">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-progress"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Resources Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Resources" icon="mb-icon icon-resources" ui-sref="tab.resources">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-resources"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: can you clarify this sentence? 
"when I click on the 'Resources' tab, it will not take me to that view. It only shows "Inside Page 2". I can only get to "Resources" if I had visited that tab first." which tab is "that" in "that tab" refers to?

Comment: When the user loads the app they see the "Home".

If they click a link to take them to "Inside Page 2" from "Home", they can no longer get to "Resources". 

If the user loads the app, goes to "Resources", then goes to "Inside Page 2" from menu there, "Inside Page 2" has a back button to get back to "Resources"